# Failed to apply delegate: TfLiteGpuDelegate Init: MUL: Expected a 3D tensor of shape HxWxC or a 4D tensor of shape 1xHxWxC but got 98x8 (Android)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I upgraded tensorflow-lite and tensorflow-lite-gpu from 2.3.0 to 2.4.0
And getting this error on initialization interpeteur

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to apply delegate: TfLiteGpuDelegate Init: MUL: Expected a 3D tensor of shape HxWxC or a 4D tensor of shape 1xHxWxC but got 98x8 TfLiteGpuDelegate Prepare: delegate is not initialized Node number 329 (TfLiteGpuDelegateV2) failed to prepare.

```
val tfliteOptions = Interpreter
.Options()
.setNumThreads(THREADS_COUNT)
.addDelegate(GpuDelegate())

Interpreter(loadModelFile(context), tfliteOptions)
```

The problem is somewhere in tensorflow-lite-gpu 2.4.0

If i'm using such configuration with older version all works well

```
implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.4.0")
implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.3.0")
```

2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.7.0, 2.8.0 Gpu delegates not working

**Issue on GitHub**
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45845

**Sample android project how to reproduce**
https://github.com/OleksandrGrument/GpuDelegateBugReproduce

**Tflite Model**
https://github.com/OleksandrGrument/GpuDelegateBugReproduce/blob/master/app/src/main/assets/model.tflite

I have opened a thread on github but no results for 2 years, maybe someone have idea how to bypass this error by changing somehow tflite file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue, before converting to tflite I changed

```
tf.math.multiply(weights, var)
```

to

```
tf.linalg.matmul(weights, var, transpose_a=True)
```

Looks like from version 2.4.0 Gpu Delegate can't proceed this operation to multiply 2d arrays with tf.math.multiply.